# How to connect to exposed port of Linux docker container from Windows host

Tags: windows, docker, port, forwarding

I have a fresh install of Docker Desktop on a Windows 10 Enterprise host and have created a container running a React app on port 9090 that exposes port 9090 running a node:10.15.3 image.  I'm able to curl 9090 from within the container and get to the app, but I'm not able to connect to the app from my Windows host.

What default settings within docker or the host do I need to modify in order to be able to connect to the app that is being forwarded to 9090?

**EDIT - Adding dockerfile and docker run command**

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.15.3

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./ /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 9090

CMD["npm", "start"]
```

Docker run command: 
`docker run -ti -p 9090:9090 28f`

Comment: When you say "exposed port" - do you mean there is an `EXPOSE` directive in the `Dockerfile`, or did you run it with `--port 9090:9090`. If the former, try running with the latter. It would help if you post a minimal version of your `Dockerfile` and the command you used.

Comment: I've updated the question with the Dockerfile as well as the docker run command.  Thanks!

Comment: If you were running the application without Docker, how would you connect to it?  Does the exact same thing work with this `docker run` command?

Comment: If I'm running it from my Windows host, the `npm run start` command starts the app on port 9090 and I connect to it via `localhost:9090`.  The app then runs fine on localhost.